# Redshift - optimal way to group by and select multiple non-aggregate columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to aggregate a table based on grouping a column. The table looks like this-

[image]

The primary objective is to get a sum based on similar IDs -

```
SELECT id,sum(amt) FROM tbl GROUP BY id;
```

This returns a valid result where the 'amt' column is summed up correctly -
[image]

But in addition to this I also want to get other columns based on certain logic. A result like this -

[image]

I tried -

```
SELECT id, sum(amt), location, date FROM tbl GROUP BY id;
```

This fails because the GROUP BY clause does not have the columns in the SELECT clause(location, date etc.).My only option here is to use other aggregate functions like MIN(), MAX() etc.

To circumvent this I tried a different approach using window functions in Redshift like this -

```
WITH AGG_TBL AS
(
  SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS ROW,
         id,
         SUM(amt) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS sum,
         location,
         date
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT x.*
FROM AGG_TBL x
WHERE x.row = 1
```

The code above selects the first row based on the partition logic and I'm able to select multiple columns.

**I will be running this aggregation query on 600+million rows so I want to know if this is indeed the most optimal way to do this in Redshift or if there is a better more efficient way?**

Comment: So are you saying that you want the extra columns to be sourced from the first row that contains the given `id`? It's normally not a good idea to assume the order of rows in the database. Would you be willing to use `MIN()` value of those fields instead of "first row"?

Comment: Let's just assume for a moment that I don't really care for the order of the rows. Are you saying do a simply GROUP BY 'id' and then use MIN() for every column? Wouldn't that mix and match results from multiple rows based on column values? Unless there is a huge performance differential, I'd rather have something that picks everything from the first row.

Comment: If you don't mind which values come back for `location` and `date`, you could use: `SELECT id, SUM(amt), MIN(location), MIN(date) FROM tbl GROUP BY id` That would be a very efficient query.

Comment: How much of a penalty is it to use the Temp Table and the window functions?

Comment: You'll have to run some tests to determine that based on your query and the data. It will consume more reasons that a straight-forward query.